# How to copy programatically the source code of a webpage?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Sharp develop. I am making a windows form application using C#. In this application i am using a webbrowser control. I want that When i open a webpage My webbrowser should programatically copy the source code of that webpage to a text file. I am using the following code to do this task

```
string MSDNpage1 = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText;
cxz.My.MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("F:\\Assignment.txt", MSDNpage1, true);
```

But this is giving an error as

> " The type or namespace Name "My" doesnot exist in the namespace cxz(are u missing assembly refrence?)( CS0234)"

Comment: Can you be more specific, what kind of webpages, html, aspx, php?

Comment: You can use `WebClient`.

Comment: The runtime could not find your class named My inside the namespace cxz.Make sure that you have added the references properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `My` keyword exists in VB.Net not C#. Here is the code to write text to a file in C#:

```
// Compose a string that consists of three lines.
string lines = "First line.\r\nSecond line.\r\nThird line.";

// Write the string to a file.
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
file.WriteLine(lines);

file.Close();
```

Ref: [Code: Writing to a Text File Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Question is that This is copying the source of a webpage but when i open a new webpage it overwites the source of new webpage to the previous data in file. Where i want that new data should save down to previous . What is the write way to do that ??